# Using same connection object to delete parent and child table

Tags: java, sql

I came across old code in my project where a same connection object is used to delete data from both parent and child tables.

```
public void delete()
{
  Connectio con = // Create a connection 
  deleteChildData(con);  // Delete data from child table/ associated table first
  super.delete(con)  //    Delete data from parent table

}
```

The obvious thing is unless i am not closing connection in this deleteChildData() function its fine. But i am not sure what can be other complications with this approach and if i use 2 different connection object whether it will be better approach to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

JDBC Transaction let you control how and when a transaction should commit into database.

To put this in a transaction, you can use

1. `dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);` to start a transaction block.
2. `dbConnection.commit();` to end a transaction block.

Your method will execute in following sequence:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatementDelete = null;

        con.setAutoCommit(false);

        preparedStatementDelete = con.prepareStatement("DELETE_QUERY");

        preparedStatementDelete.executeUpdate();

        con.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating new connection is costlier when there is already a connection is created and available . So better try to reuse the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Obtaining a database connection(which is a *resource*, other examples can be file handle,etc.) is costly. So if you can choose painlessly from using 1 or 2 connection(s), the former would have better performance.

However, we have a pattern called **connection pools**, which stores a number of connections somewhere(not releasing each one right after a transaction or a function), so you don't have to close a connection after some SQL queries, and just apply to the pool manager for a connection when you need one(and let the manager take a connection from the pool or create a new one when there's none left in the pool for you). Connection pooling improves performance a lot while only takes up a bit memory and some extra CPU cycles when starting up the server(obtaining initial amount of connections), so most people use it.

Then if you use a connection pool, there's not really much difference between using 1 or 2 connections in your method(unless the 2nd one happens to make the pool manager to create a new connection).

Most JVM-based servers provide connection pooling functionality, you can refer to the respective docs for usage. But sure, it would be really much refactoring if your project didn't use that before, so the answer in short for your question might be "1".